# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting the following error :

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

The numbers are not too big for `bigint`. I am unable to point out what is going wrong here. Any pointers please.

Query

```
DECLARE SP bigint
DECLARE LP bigint

SET SP = 125000000 
SET LP = 88300000 

SELECT a = CAST((AVG(LP * 100 / CAST(SP AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: Are you sure that's your query and your output? You're missing the `@` on your variables, and it should overflow converting to numeric, not int. At least that's what happens on SQL2008.

Comment: @JoeEnos Inorder not to overwhelm I put only the erroring portion of my query.

Comment: It makes a big difference - your query that you posted will overflow because of the cast to a decimal. If you're getting an overflow error while casting to an int, then what you've posted is not applicable.

Comment: Try posting a reproduction of your problem on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can see exactly the error, without any transcription problems.

Comment: `DECIMAL(10,2)` gives you a decimal with a total of 10 digits, 2 of which after the decimal point - so 8 digits before the decimal point. **BUT** your `SP` value (which should be `@SP`, really) has **nine** digits - this **cannot** be converted to `DECIMAL(10,2)`! You need to use *more digits* in your decimal type, e.g. `DECIMAL(16,2)` or something like that

Answer (score 2):

I think your int error is coming from the division.  You should also be able to move the 100* out of the `AVG` function and not `CAST` quite so often:

```
DECLARE @SP bigint
DECLARE @LP bigint

SET @SP = 125000000
SET @LP = 88300000 

select a= 100 * avg(@LP / cast(@SP as float))
```

also, see [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=127160) regarding division of bigints

Comment: If you want to see every last bit of the pi, use this `select a= 100 * avg(@LP / cast(@SP as float(24)))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SP bigint
DECLARE @LP bigint

SET @SP = 125000000 
SET @LP = 88300000 

SELECT a = CAST((AVG(@LP * 100 / CAST(@SP AS DECIMAL(12, 2)))) AS DECIMAL(12,2))
```

I agree with marc_s comment, `@SP` has nine digits - this cannot be converted to `DECIMAL(10,2)` You need to use more digits in your decimal type, e.g. DECIMAL(16,2)` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

What did you try? It would have been less work just to break down the problem youself than post syntax that is not even valid on SO.

This fails

```
DECLARE @SP bigint
SET @SP = 125000000
select cast(@SP as decimal(10,2))
```